# How to group at the for loop through the second condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, group

unfortunately I'm having trouble creating a correct display of mianowiecie values.
I have such a DF:

| Group | Match | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A1 |
| A | 1 | A2 |
| A | 2 | A3 |
| A | 2 | A4 |

I have this code:

```
for group in set(world_cup['Group']):
    print('___Starting group {}:___'.format(group))
    for home, away in combinations(world_cup.query('Group == "{}"'.format(group)).index, 2):
      #conditions....
```

I added a third loop so that instead of selecting group it selects game. However, I do not get the expected result because it shows all the matches in one group first and then the same matches in other groups. I would like to get something like this:

```
___Starting group A:__
A1-A2
A3-A4
```

Now I get something like this

```
___Starting group A:__
A1-A2
A1-A3
A1-A4
A2-A3
A2-A4
A3-A4
```

Thank everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood you correctly. You can `.groupby()` and then `.agg` the values:

```py
out = df.groupby(["Group", "Match"]).agg("-".join)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
              Team
Group Match       
A     1      A1-A2
      2      A3-A4
```

---

```py
out = df.groupby(["Group", "Match"]).agg("-".join)

tmp = {}
for idx, row in out.iterrows():
    tmp.setdefault(idx[0], []).append(row["Team"])

for k, v in tmp.items():
    print("___Starting group {}:___".format(k))
    for vv in v:
        print(vv)
```

Prints:

```
___Starting group A:___
A1-A2
A3-A4
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. Unfortunately I don't mean to print that way. It has to be automated and I can't use group by by the fact that I have an index on the team and it has to be there. I mean that in combinations instead of 'Group == "{}"'.format(group) it should be 'Match == "{}"'.format(game(i.e)). The only problem I have with this is that I don't know how I can match the value of game